# PostgreSQL CTE records as parameters to function

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that accepts two integers as parameters **my_function(input_a, input_b)**.  Is there an easy way to pass the results of a CTE (that returns records of **input_a, input_b**) into the function?

Should I be looking into writing a custom function with a for loop or is there a better approach?

Comment: `with cte as (select 1 a,2 b) select my_function(a,b) from cte;` does not work?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function returns a single record then:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 a, 2 b)
SELECT my_function(a, b) FROM cte;
```

will work.  However, if the function is an SRF (Set-Returning-Function), then you need to use LATERAL, to let the database know that you want to feed the results of the prior tables in the JOIN statement to the functions later on in the JOIN.  This is accomplished like so:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 a, 2 b)
SELECT * FROM cte, LATERAL my_function(a, b);
```

The LATERAL will cause PostgreSQL to take each row from the CTE and run "my_function" with the values from that row, returning the results of that function to the overall SELECT statement.