# Postgres: Refer to CTE alias within function

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I want to do something like this:

```
...
with blocking_index as (
  (select * from exact_phone_matches) union all (select * from 
   exact_email_matches)
), 
matched_names as (
  select * from get_matches((_rec.name, 'blocking_index')
  )
)
...
```

i.e. I want to pass the reference to my CTE alias ('blocking_index') into a function. This function contains something like this:

```
return query execute format('select * from %s where %s', _table, _whr)
```

This doesn't work. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: closest thing I can find is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670995/postgresql-cte-records-as-parameters-to-function ... would have to rewrite the function so that it  works on one record at a time...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with a CTE which has no meaning outside the query where it is defined.

What you could use is a temporary table. That has the added advantage that you can `ANALYZE` it so the optimizer has statistics, which is not possible with a CTE.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but this query would be executed many times, from user triggered contact searches, and batch contact dedupe runs (once per contact),.. so I need the query to be fast and efficient - i.e. 100ms - wouldn't creating a temp table each time involve more overhead?

Comment: Maybe, but I see no alternative.